# Is there anyway to trigger signal r notification from client application using javascript outside the project?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, web, signalr

I have implemented signal R inside my application, Am in a scenario that client needs to send a notification to my hub, Is there any possibility to achieve this  using javascript

......Code to get notifcation


So the client can execute the script so that I can get the notification here inside my project

Answer (score 0):

You can have the client call a method on the server including passing parameters if needed.

If you are not using .Net Core, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#how-to-call-server-methods-from-the-client

If you are using .Net Core, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-5.0#call-hub-methods-from-the-client